# install4j / vm runtime parameter -J-Xmx not applied

Tags: install4j

Hi I'm using install4j (v8) for Windows. The installer configuration allows "VM passthrough parameters", but extending the vmoption file of my application by

-J-Xms256m

-J-Xmx768m

is not applied. The application/JVM is still using the defaults provided by the installer config.

Any idea/comments?

vmoption file extended by following lines:

-J-Xms256m

-J-Xmx768m

Answer (score 0):

install4j 8.0.2 fixed the issue that VM passthrough parameters prefixed with -J were not added after the .vmoptions file so they would not override values in the .vmoptions file.

It seems that you are using a previous version.You can download install4j 8.0.11 here: https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/install4j/version_80

Comment: Thanks for the notice. Just double-checked the package which was already build with .11 as per i4jparams.conf.  

<config install4jVersion="8.0.11" install4jBuild="8268" type="windows" archive="false" bitness="64">  

A recent local (re-)build with that install4j version seems to still ignore "-J".

Comment: I cannot reproduce that with the current version. Adding -J-Xmx768m on the command line overrides the -Xmx value in the .vmoptions file as well as the -Xmx value in the fixed VM parameters of the launcher configuration. Can you try with the current version as well?

Comment: Thanks again. Apologize, my mistake! I put "-J-Xmx768m" in the vmoption file instead of simply "-Xmx768m". The alternative as command line arg would not be suitable in our case.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood what you were doing. Indeed, the -J prefix is only to turn command line arguments into VM parameters.